# How to use Django slugs creatively

Tags: django, django-templates

In my frontpage.html. I have two buttons that link to the different categories of products I have I was using a for loop to get the slug needed for the URL link In the button, but this causes issues because it renders two buttons for each category i created in the models. My question: Is there a way for Django to only use one of these category slugs so I can specifically pick which URL it will render? I attached a picture of the frontpage.html file notice the for loop I am using to get the category slug that is being used to render the correct detail page. a for loop won't work since i have multiple categories

[image: Here is what is rendered]

```
HTML

 {% for category in menu_categories %}
                <a href="{% url 'category_detail' category.slug %}">Get Started</a>
                {% endfor %}
```

```
models.py for categories


class Category(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
   ordering = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here is the models.py as well. I was thinking there should be a way to explicitly call a specific slug and not render both buttons right next to each other